# eclipse plugin: save animated image into PC

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt

I have a image loader which loads the image and save it into the PC as follows:

```
ImageLoader saver = new ImageLoader();
saver.data = new ImageData[] { ImageDescriptor.createFromURL(
            FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("icons/img.gif"), null))
            .createImage().getImageData() };
saver.save("D:/img.gif", SWT.IMAGE_GIF);
```

But when i trying to save animated gif, the saved image is not animated. How could i save the animated image from the bundle to the user PC ?

Answer (score 0):

As the code show, you have only one `ImageData`.
For an animated GIF, you need several `ImageData`. `ImageDescriptor` doesn't allow that; it is too high level, you need to use SWT directly:

```
final ImageLoader loader = new ImageLoader();
loader.load(FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("icons/img.gif"), null).openStream()); // closing the stream would be appreciable :)
```

You can then try to save directly, but I think the SWT library is unable to save animated GIF.
If you still want to use SWT for that, you must save each image one by one:

```
int i=0;
for (ImageData data : loader.data) {
    final ImageLoader saver = new ImageLoader();
    saver.save("image-" + (i++) + ".gif", SWT.IMAGE_GIF);
}
```